# Percentage Numbers in 2 Combobox

Tags: c#, textbox

I have 2 combo boxes:

1. To receive a percentage (temperature * this percentage)
2. To receive the other percentage (temperature * this percentage)

1 and 2 must sum 100% -> This will create a weight for each temperature

What do I already have: 2 Comboboxes that receive these values;

What do I need:
While the user input one %, it locks the other; Also, the user can start input the % in either Comboboxes

```
private void TextBoxInletPercentage_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int val = 0;
    int other_val = 0;
    bool res = Int32.TryParse(TextBoxInletPercentage.Text, out val);
    if (res == true && val > -1 && val < 101)
    {
        // add record
        other_val = (100 - val);
        TextBoxOutletPercentage.Enabled = false;
        TextBoxOutletPercentage.Text = other_val.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please input a percentage between 0 to 100 only.");
        return;
    }


}

private void TextBoxOutletPercentage_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int val = 0;
    int other_val = 0;
    bool res = Int32.TryParse(TextBoxOutletPercentage.Text, out val);
    if (res == true && val > -1 && val < 101)
    {
        // add record
        other_val = (100 - val);
        TextBoxInletPercentage.Enabled = false;
        TextBoxInletPercentage.Text = other_val.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please input a percentage between 0 to 100 only.");
        return;
    }

}
```

Problem: It is only allowing me to enter 1 caracter the ComboBox. After the first number, it automatic freeze.

Comment: put try/catch block and check if you get any specific error

Comment: trace it you should see where it gets stuck

Comment: I suspect both events are firing, because when this code modifies the other input then that will trigger the event on the other input.  Why exactly does the other input need to be disabled?  Once the user modifies either input, the code would automatically adjust the other one.  What does disabling actually accomplish for the user experience?

Comment: Have you tried the Leave event instead. That way it will only "freeze" the other textbox after you are done entering the value.

Comment: @David, that is a good point! If I take out the "disable", the other combo box will be with the (Value first Combobox) - 100 (what I need!). I think that it will work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever the `Text` property of `TextBox` is changed the event `TextChanged` will be raised - regardless what was the cause of that change (by user-input or by code).

You need to handle the event different if the change was made by user or by your code. Just check the `Enabled` property for this.

```
private void InletPercentage_TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HandleTextBox(InletPercentage_TextBox, OutletPercentage_TextBox);
}

private void OutletPercentage_TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HandleTextBox(OutletPercentage_TextBox, InletPercentage_TextBox);
}

private void HandleTextBox(TextBox me, TextBox other)
{
    // if not enabled then it is not user input and just leave
    if (!me.Enabled) return;

    // if the user has cleared the input, reset other to accept input on both again
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(me.Text))
    {
        other.Text = string.Empty;
        other.Enabled = true;
        return;
    }

    // handle user input
    other.Enabled = false;

    int value;
    if (int.TryParse(me.Text, out value) && value >= 0 && value <= 100)
    {
        other.Text = (100 - value).ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        other.Text = string.Empty;
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid input");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering.
However, I am getting a "NullReferenceException was unhandled" when I enter a first digit in any of the ComboBoxes. Do you know what may be happening? I tried to take some screenshots to show the problem: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B98UpTa2n4XbeHZtOHU2cVotUms?usp=sharing

Comment: Well, you should pass **your** TextBox references to the method like HandleTextBox( TextBoxInletPercentage, TextBoxOutletPercentage ) - passing *null* values will of course produce exceptions

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in the TextChanged event. When you start typing (1 character is entered), it would start evaluating. If it is a valid number -- it would disable the other textbox and change the text on that textbox. This would trigger the effect from the other textbox which should be a valid number -- and thus disabling your current textbox resulting in a freeze like nature.

Try TextBoxOutletPercentage_Leave -- which should be triggered when you move away from that textbox.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `TextChanged` events not only fired by manual input, but also fired by changing the text programmatically.

When you are typing in `Inlet`, and if it's a valid value, it will update `Outlet` with a valid value for sure, which will then propagate back to `Inlet`. Luckily at this time it should have the same value thus no further propagation, but if one of the calculation goes wrong, it will in a deadlock forever.

However, as both of your `TextChanged` events disables the other output, you will anyway end up with both disabled text box.

**The quickest fix is to use `KeyUp` event but TBH it's not the optimum way of doing that.**

Better, you probably may consider to use a `TrackBar` to adjust the values, and two `Label` to display the values, as both `Inlet` and `Outlet` should adds up to 100. I can imagine if the space of window is limited, and the use requires precise control, this may not be the best way, but otherwise, it could make the user's life much easier.

In your current logic, at the beginning, unless you pre set the values, it will both zero, and when you click some button to proceed your process, you need another validation if both values are valid. The added validation will easily cause program fragile. Also, using message box may not the best practise in programming.

Lastly, I assume you do not wish to limit the user to change only one box, or in other words, if the user initially changed the value in `Inlet`, and later decide to change it into another value, but in `Outlet`, you should allow the user to do so rather than letting the user to calculate the value that supposed to be put in `Inlet`. Your current logic will disable the `Outlet` permanently once the user put anything in `Inlet`, and vice versa.

E.g, at the beginning, the user want `Inlet` to be 24, it will calculate `Outlet` automatically, but the user may found, oh no, I should put `Outlet` as 24. What will the user have to do? S/he will have to calculate `Inlet` suppose to be 100-24=76, and put 76 in `Inlet` and let the programme fill `Outlet`. This is unnatural, difficult and error problematic. How about just letting the user to type in `Outlet` if s/he changed the mind?

To achieve this usability, you may want to add a `Leave` event to enable the other `TextBox`. But, hold on, what's the purpose of disabling in the first instance? You cannot update both `TextBox` simultaneously so disabling the other `TextBox` while typing and enabling it while leaving is useless except the illusion. Why not just remove the line of disabling the other box?

Answer (score 0):

You can try insert condition

```
if (!TextBoxOutletPercentage.Focused)
                    TextBoxOutletPercentage.Enabled = false;
```

into TextBoxInletPercentage_TextChanged
and

```
if(!TextBoxInletPercentage.Focused)
                    TextBoxInletPercentage.Enabled = false;
```

into TextBoxOutletPercentage_TextChanged

It will ensure that only one combobox will be disabled, but you have to think of the logic when to enable both to be able to edit the secondone